# Как записать отдельно значения из массива в json файл?

Tags: python, json

У меня есть 3 файла:

```
Песня1.mp3
Песня2.mp3
Песня3.mp3
```

И я написал вот такой скрипт для получения названий песен и записи их в список:

```
import glob, os

massiv = []

for file in glob.glob("*.mp3"):
  massiv.append(str(file))
print(massiv)
```

И он выдаёт вот такой итог:

```
['Песня1.mp3', 'Песня2.mp3', 'Песня3.mp3']
```

Как записать названия песен из списка в json-файл вот такого содержания:

```
[{"title":"Тут название песни1","file":"https://site.com/Тут название песни1"},
{"title":"Тут название песни2","file":"https://site.com/Тут название песни2"},
# и т.д.
]
```

P.S.
Песен будет много (не 3 точно)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте стандартный модуль `json`.

```
import json

arr = ['Песня1.mp3', 'Песня2.mp3', 'Песня3.mp3']

obj = []

for item in arr:
    obj.append({'title': item,
                'file': f'https://site.com/{item}'})

with open('out.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(obj, f, indent=2)
```